# robots.txt file per environment

Tags: 8

We are using Drupal 8.9 and we have an EC2 stage site and our main site, which use the same code base.

Is it possible to have a different robots.txt file for each site (environment)?

We don't want the stage site to appears on search results.

Comment: Use the RobotsTxt module.

Comment: If it's about disallowing robots on a stage site, I'd simply put server-side basic authentication like a .htpasswd up front. Password can be simple, memorisable if it's just for keeping robots out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's the [RobotsTxt](https://www.drupal.org/project/robotstxt) module that in the end after you removed the robots.txt file takes config to provide the contents of a /robots.txt page.

Together with the [Configuration Split](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_split) module you can then have it play different contents per environment.

---

To exclude Drupal's default robots.txt file from being recreated during scaffolding, adjust the `file-mapping` in composer.json like that:

```json
"drupal-scaffold": {
    "locations": {
        "web-root": "web/"
    },
    "file-mapping": {
        "[web-root]/robots.txt": false
    }
},
```

Comment: RobotsTxt also nice for multi-sites.

Answer (score 1):

I patch the root `.htaccess` file to redirect to a deny-robots.txt file (which will appear as robots.txt in the reponse) based on the domain, but you could easily use the same directives in your apache configuration:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Deny robots everywhere except the production site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com\.au$
RewriteRule ^robots.txt(\??.*)$ deny-robots.txt$1
```

Contents of deny-robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: *
```

Comment: The reason I patch the drupal `.htaccess` file instead of putting this in apache config is I use the same apache config between a few different sites.